# How can I get keys from map in c++ in any form?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I want to get all keys from a collection, is there a standard way to do this?

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, size_t> map;
auto keys = map.get_keys();
```

Comment: What special do you expect from `auto keys`? Your `map` is already a kind of collection of keys. The vector of keys can be collected by `for(auto v: map) keys.push_back(v.first);`

Comment: You can always iterate over all the key value pairs using a range based loop? For what would you need all keys lsited separately?

Answer (score 2):

```
for( const auto& n : map ) {
        std::cout << "Key:[" << n.first << "]\n";
}
```